# Cumulative sum of triangular matrix numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix, cumsum

Say I have the following `numpy array`:

```
a = np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]])
```

And I want the cumulative sum array-wise like this:

```
a.cumsum(axis=1)
array([[ 1.,  3.,  6.],
       [ 1.,  3.,  6.],
       [ 1.,  3.,  6.]])
```

Is there any way to do the same with a triangular array/matrix?

```
b = np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [2.0, 3.0], [3.0]])
```

Basically the following result:

```
array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [2.0, 5.0], [3.0]], dtype=object)
```

I tried the following but I get the following error message:

```
b.cumsum(axis=1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-76-831556b68f3f>", line 1, in <module>
    b.cumsum(axis=1)
ValueError: axis(=1) out of bounds
```

Should I try to redefine `b` in order to have `nan` values? I'd like to avoid adding zeroes as the end of my smaller arrays (my real arrays could contains zeros, which for me is different than having no values at all).

Comment: The term is "ragged array/matrix" I think. So, with that, you can simply loop through and apply cumsum per element. Follow up question - How did you end up with such an array/matrix?

Comment: Alternative suggestion, if you are getting b from a - Use `np.triu(a).cumsum(1)` and then get rid of the leading zeros per row, probably with another `triu` mask, depending final expected o/p.

Comment: If you want to store a triangular array in an economic way use LAPACK standart. This one is just wasting a good chunk of performance with `object` datatype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is based on false premise. There is no such thing as a triangular array in NumPy, so it does not make sense to ask how to find a cumulative some of one. If you write

```
b = np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [2.0, 3.0], [3.0]])
```

you get a **one-dimensional** array of the kind `array([object, object, object])`. There is no matrix structure here, no axes to swap, no ufuncs to apply, really nothing NumPy-related. Just a bunch of Python objects which happen to be Python lists (they are not NumPy arrays).

Representing missing values by NaN is a common thing to do.

```
row_list = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [2.0, 3.0], [3.0]]
max_length = max([len(row) for row in row_list])
b = np.array([row + [np.nan]*(max_length - len(row)) for row in row_list])
```

Now `b` is an honest float-datatype NumPy array, to which you can apply `cumsum` or whatever.

```
b.cumsum(axis=1)
```

returns

```
array([[  1.,   3.,   6.],
       [  2.,   5.,  nan],
       [  3.,  nan,  nan]])
```

There is [`masked array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) module for more complex things of this kind, but NaN-padding works fine for basic operations on a ragged matrix. Some other things one can do:

```
np.nansum(b, axis=1)    # sum, ignoring NaN 
np.nanmean(b, axis=1)   # mean, ignoring NaN
np.isnan(b)             # find where NaN are in the array
```

Comment: I get what you mean, thank you very much for the clarification!